# Entering path containing spaces in Terminal

Tags: macos, command-line, filesystem

Working on my MacBook Pro, I want to change the location of my iPhone backup to an external drive, but when entering the command on the CLI I hadn't noticed that the destination drive has a space in the name (HARDDRV BKUP). How would I enter the following

```
ln -s /Volumes/HARDDRV BKUP/iphonebkup/Backup/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
```

using "HARDDRV BKUP" as the name of the external drive in Terminal?  If I recall correctly, the CLI doesn't interpret SPACES the same way, and capitalization is important to take into account as well, correct?  Can someone here correct this for me?

I am new at using the CLI and most of my experience is using the GUI, so I am getting very frustrated and don't have the energy to research all my notes on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose one of the following:

- Surround the part of the path containing spaces in quotes:

  ```
  ln -s /Volumes/"HARDDRV BKUP"/iphonebkup/Backup/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
                 ^            ^
  ```
- Surround the entire path in quotes:

  ```
  ln -s "/Volumes/HARDDRV BKUP/iphonebkup/Backup/" ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
        ^                                        ^
  ```
- Escape the space with a backslash `\`:

  ```
  ln -s /Volumes/HARDDRV\ BKUP/iphonebkup/Backup/ ~/Library/Application\ Support/MobileSync
                        ^
  ```

Case sensitivity is important in these cases.

Comment: I was unaware about the first one. Very elegant!

Comment: You can also drag files and folders from the Finder into a Terminal window, and it'll insert an appropriately-escaped-for-shell version of the path.